# How to receive IPv4 packets using SOCK_RAW in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, ip, packet

How do I receive network layer (OSI Layer 3) packets in Linux? More specifically, IPv4 packets regardless of transport layer protocol (UDP, TCP, ...). Preferably in C without libraries.

Using `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)`, I'm only able to send IPv4 packets; not receive.

Comment: "I'm only able to send IPv4 packets; not receive". Please show your code. We can't point out any problems if we can't see it.

Comment: Also see [Raw Socket promiscuous mode not sniffing what I write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12177708/608639), [Filter packets in network stack while sniffing packets on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9752583/608639) and [Read raw IPv4 in promiscuous mode on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27069400/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `recvfrom` from socket library. Like in this example :

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , protocol);
while(1)
{
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &addr , &addr_size);
}
```

Comment: "regardless of transport layer protocol (UDP, TCP, ...)". OP wants to receive all IP packets. Does your code do that?

Comment: @Victor Fonne I think your answer is correct, but with the wrong emphasis (so maybe just edit it a bit). The key is `SOCK_RAW`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html